# Unique hits (php) counted as a pair (w/ comma)

Tags: php, ip, unique

This isn't so much a "OMG EVERYTHING IS BREAKING" as it is a "What's going on here?"

Found this php code to count unique hits - basically what it does is places the IP into a text file and then counts how many unique IPs are in that file.

```
    $filename = "/XXX/XXX/public_html/XXX.txt";
    if (!file_exists($filename))
    {
    $fd = fopen($filename, "w+");
    fclose($fd);
    }
    $file = file($filename);
    $file = array_unique($file);
    $hits = count($file);
    $fd = fopen($filename, "r");
    $fstring = fread($fd, filesize($filename));
    fclose($fd);
    $fd = fopen($filename, "w");
    $fcounted = $fstring . "
    " . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    $fout = fwrite($fd, $fcounted);
    fclose($fd);
```

However, on a couple of occasions, I will notice that a few IPs are being inserted as a comma separated pair.

Normally, it would be:

```
1.1.1.1

2.2.2.2

3.3.3.3
```

However, a few lines exist like this:

```
1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2
```

Since the code works without a hitch 99% of the time, and the comma separation only happens on a rare occasion, I'm inclined to believe it's something other than the code.  Any ideas?  (And no, XXX is not the name of the file nor the path to it.)

HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR so it can get around Cloudflare (otherwise it'd just post Cloudflare's IPs)

Comment: You can't trust that IP header. Probably a proxy messes it up and attaches forwarded IP address.

Comment: If you have access to a Database - storing IP addresses there would make more sense as you can maintain more data and get more statistics from it.  IE you'll be able to see more than unique addresses - you'll be able to see how many times that specific IP requested the resource... Throw in a timestamp field as well and you'll be able to know *when* it happened too..

Comment: Worth noting, that more rational storing of an IP address would be as a number. Just apply `ip2long()` function to it. To convert from number to readable: `long2ip()`.